# Установить заранее известный IP адрес клиенту при подключении к разным Wi-Fi сетям

Tags: java, android, windows, сеть, wifi

**Суть проблемы:**

Есть ноут, он подсоединяется к домашнему Wi-Fi или к точке доступа с телефона. На ноуте запускается веб-сервер, к которому подключается приложение на телефоне. Соответственно, для приложения надо указывать адрес сервера. В разных Wi-Fi сетях адрес у ноута разный (192.168.0.xxx и 192.168.43.xxx). В итоге приходится делать разные сборки приложения на телефоне, указывая тот или иной адрес ноута, что неудобно.

**Вопрос:**

Возможно ли в принципе так настроить роутер дома или точку доступа на телефоне или что-то на ноуте (win10) чтобы ноут в указанных Wi-Fi сетях всегда имел `заранее определённый одинаковый` IP адрес?

Comment: Теоретически можно было бы настроить нужную подсеть и DHCP на точке доступа с телефона, но телефонов с такими расширенными настройками мне не попадалось...

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но как насчёт костыля — пробросить VPN/SSH туннель и подключаться в определённому в их конфигах айпишнику?)

Comment: Ещё не по теме вопроса, но можно например придумать в приложении скрытую настройку позволяющую сменить адрес — например я такое видел у ВК в инженерном меню `*#*#856682583#*#*` https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUiZV.png

Comment: @andreymal 1. Вот [тут](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499) нашёл инфу о том, что некоторые девайсы таки позволяют менять расширенные настройки точки доступа на телефоне. Однако в моём девайсе (Xiomi MiMix2s) такого нет. Там же написано, что можно системное приложение пересобрать, прописав там нужные IP. Однако звучит довольно страшно и сложно(

Comment: @andreymal 2. А это на какой стороне надо делать? На тестовом девайсе? Или на ноуте? Если последнее то, наверное, такое бы мне подошло - можно немного подробнее? Что гуглить хотя бы)

Comment: @andreymal 3. Такой вариант можно рассмотреть да. Однако хотелось бы избежать добавления дополнительного кода в приложение)

Comment: 2. На обоих (сервер на ноуте, клиент на телефоне). Как дела с VPN-серверами на винде, я не в курсе (у себя на линуксе использую wireguard, с андроидом дружит хорошо), но зато в win10 из коробки уже есть SSH-сервер (но нужно настроить по инструкциям из гугла), а дальше на андроиде любым подручным SSH-клиентом (JuiceSSH, Termux и т.д.) [можно пробросить нужный порт](https://hostadmina.ru/blog/linux/ssh/probros-portov-cherez-ssh-tunnel.html) `ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234 192.168.0.2` и в приложении уже подключаться к `127.0.0.1:1234` (правда, порты ниже 1024 не пробросятся из-за безопасности)

Comment: @andreymal 2. Правильно ли я понимаю, что достаточно будет в разных Wi-Fi сетях с телефона выполнять команду `ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234 192.168.x.y`, указывая последним аргументом текущий IP ноута? Коли так, то это похоже на рабочее решение - всяко проще рутования каждого андроид девайса или добавления настроек в приложение)

Comment: Да. Но если нужно прокинуть что-то вроде http (порт 80 или 443), то андроид (точнее ядро линукса) не даст этого сделать по соображениям безопасности и придётся пробрасывать http на какой-то другой порт и прописывать его в приложении. А если вдруг приложение архитектурно не предусматривает установку другого порта, то придётся всё-таки с VPN возиться наверное

Comment: @andreymal У меня в данный момент в приложении вот такое указано в качестве адреса сервера на ноуте: `http://192.168.0.102:8080`. Получается, что я смогу с телефона выполнить `ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234 192.168.0.102:8080` и оно будет работать как только я в приложении адрес сервера сменю на `http://127.0.0.1:1234`?

Comment: `ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 192.168.0.102` и адрес `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: @andreymal, понял, круто, спасибо) Попробую вечером проверить как оно работает) Напишете это в ответ? =)

Comment: Очень сильно сомневаюсь, что это является ответом на вопрос, потому что он про настройку сети всё-таки

Comment: Ну, это вопрос так сформулирован, вроде как получается [XY проблема](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/311724) Т.е. это вполне ответ, так как мою проблему вполне решает. Просто не предполагаемым мною изначально способом)

Comment: (в JuiceSSH проброс порта оказывается платная опция... Но ладно, в гугл-плее наверняка найдётся SSH-клиент с бесплатным пробросом портов)) Хотя лично я использую Termux, который предоставляет Debian-подобную командную строку с ssh как одной из доступных команд)

Comment: можно за 2$ в месяц взять https://www.ionos.com/servers/vps и не городить городушку

Comment: @nörbörnën думаю, прописать две команды в powershell винды всё-таки несколько проще)

Comment: @nörbörnën, сервер у меня уже есть, мне надо именно к локальному серверу на ноуте подключаться)

Comment: @andreymal, попробовал termux - при выполнении такое получаю: `ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 192.168.43.226
ssh: connect to host 192.168.43.226 port 22: Connection timed out` Видать на винде тоже что-то настраивать надо(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну да, [ssh-сервер включить](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

Comment: @andreymal, ага, так работает) Пришлось, правда, вручную имя юзера винды указывать в `ssh` команде - по умолчанию какое-то не то указывалось) Теперь в браузере на телефоне по адресу `127.0.0.1:8080` своё API на винде запущенное вижу, спасибо)

Comment: Кстати я тут вспомнил, что вообще-то можно было поставить SSH-сервер тупо прямо на андроид, например [SimpleSSHD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.galexander.sshd&hl=ru&gl=US)... Просто тогда в команде ssh вместо `127.0.0.1` указать текущий адрес ноута да и всё) Добавил соответствующее примечание к ответу.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Что ж, раз мне предлагают интерпретировать вопрос как [XY проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710)... Если предположить, что **истинный** вопрос подразумевает что-то вроде *«Как избавиться от необходимости обновлять IP-адрес сервера в Android-приложении при смене локальной сети?»*, то тут уже можно придумать множество разных вариантов.

---

В первую очередь любому линуксоиду придёт в голову [проброс порта через SSH](https://hostadmina.ru/blog/linux/ssh/probros-portov-cherez-ssh-tunnel.html), благо SSH-сервер установлен на любом уважающем себя линуксе.

Суть вкратце: на клиенте на локалхосте запускаем прослушивание порта, все подключения к которому будут отправлены на какой-то другой адрес, тогда локальный адрес вида `http://127.0.0.1:8080` будет постоянным, а удалённый адрес можно менять как угодно по ситуации.

На радость не-линуксоидам, SSH-сервер также есть в macOS и даже стал доступен в Windows 10 с версии 1809, в котором [установка OpenSSH](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) в принципе сводится к трём-четырём командам, запускаемым в PowerShell от имени администратора:

```
# Установка SSH-клиента (однократно)
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

# Установка SSH-клиента (однократно)
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0

# Запуск службы SSH
Start-Service sshd

# Прописывание службы SSH в автозагрузку (опционально)
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
```

При первом запуске будут автоматически сгенерированы настройки и SSH-ключи в папке `C:\ProgramData\ssh` (можно их поредактировать по вкусу и перезапустить службу).

В итоге запущенная служба предоставляет удалённый доступ к командной строке по протоколу SSH, но в контексте вопроса интересует нас не это, а встроенная в протокол возможность проброса портов.

Далее на Android ставим любой SSH-клиент, поддерживающий проброс портов. Лично я не разбираюсь во всём разнообразии клиентов, доступных в Google Play, поэтому описывать их не стану. Сам я использую команду `ssh` в командной строке, и в Android её может предоставить любое приложение, дающее Linux-окружение, например [Termux](https://f-droid.org/ru/packages/com.termux/) (SSH-клиент в нём можно установить командами `pkg update && pkg install openssh`)

Синтаксис проброса порта в команде SSH такой:

```
ssh -N -L локальный_ip:локальный_порт:удалённый_адрес:удалённый_порт имя_пользователя@адрес_сервера
```

- локальный ip — тот, на котором будет запущено прослушивание порта (по умолчанию 127.0.0.1, можно не указывать);
- локальный порт — тот, который будет прослушиваться на клиенте (не обязан совпадать с удалённым портом);
- удалённый адрес и удалённый порт — тот, к которому будет идти подключение через ssh (если указать 127.0.0.1, то будет идти подключение к устройству, на котором запущен ssh-сервер, но можно указать и любой другой адрес, к которому оно имеет доступ);
- имя пользователя должно быть существующим в Windows (работоспособность кириллицы не проверял), после подключения спросят пароль от этого пользователя;
- опция `-N` просто отключает командную строку, для проброса портов она всё равно не нужна; можно эту опцию убрать и пользоваться командной строкой, если хочется;
- можно пробросить несколько портов, повторив опцию `-L` с параметрами несколько раз.

Например, такая команда:

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:80 172.16.10.12
```

перенаправит все запросы к локальному адресу `127.0.0.1:8080` на удалённый адрес `127.0.0.1:80` (это два разных 127.0.0.1!) через сервер `172.16.10.12`.

В итоге, подключившись к нужному SSH-серверу и свернув клиент, мы получаем возможность прописать `http://127.0.0.1:8080` в нужное приложение или например открыть его в браузере. Очевидно, этот адрес не будет меняться, пока мы сами не укажем другие локальные ip и порт в настройках проброса. IP-адрес сервера может меняться при смене сети, но на локальный адрес это не повлияет — просто нужно будет немножко отредактировать эту команду.

[image]

[image]

---

Также можно не ставить SSH-сервер на Windows, а поставить его прямо на Android-устройсте (тоже есть разнообразние приложений в Google Play и F-Droid — мною проверен [SimpleSSHD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.galexander.sshd&hl=ru&gl=US), и в Termux команда `sshd` тоже имеется, но нужна предварительная настройка).

Тогда команда подключения могла бы иметь вид `ssh -L 8080:172.16.10.12:80 127.0.0.1 -p 2222` — то есть подключаемся сами к себе (к SSH-серверу на порту 2222), но перенаправляем на удалённый адрес.

---

Хотя вообще если подумать, то использовать аж целый SSH для всего лишь проброса одного порта это немножко оверкилл. Наверняка должны существовать более примитивные приложения, но тут я не в теме, можно кто-нибудь ещё напишет ответы :)

---

Ядро линукса не позволит SSH-клиенту слушать порты ниже 1024 по соображениям безопасности. Если нет возможности указать произвольный порт вместо 80 (не предусмотрено приложением) или нужно вместо TCP использовать UDP/ICMP, то придётся прокидывать полноценную сеть с помощью какого-нибудь VPN. Я не в курсе, как дела с VPN-серверами на Windows и писать подробную инструкцию не стану, но за Android могу сказать, что OpenVPN и WireGuard клиенты работают хорошо. В настройках VPN-сервера можно будет прописать выдачу конкретного IP-адреса Android-клиенту, который и будет постоянным.

---

Вместо IP-адреса можно попробовать использовать домен, а привязанный к домену IP-адрес менять на лету. Но для этого придётся поднимать свой DNS-сервер в локальной сети (муторно) или на андроиде редактировать файл `/system/etc/hosts` (естественно потребуется root-доступ).